# Can gmail notifications be customized by label?

Tags: gmail, notifications, filter

I have filters configured on my gmail account to add labels to incoming messages based on sender, subject, etc.   I'd like to configure the default gmail client to apply different notifications based on these labels.  [This post](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/2246/can-you-setup-android-gmail-to-play-a-sound-when-an-email-from-a-certain-email-ad) suggests setting up multiple gmail accounts, but that would quickly become unworkable, IMO.   I've tried to change the notification settings while in a label view, and long-pressing on the label name in the label list screen, but neither leads to the desired result.   I'm hoping there's something I've missed...

Comment: By "tags" do you mean "labels"?  And I am pretty sure this can't be done with the GMail app.

Comment: One thing you CAN do is put a shortcut to a particular Gmail label on your homescreen. That'd make it easy to jump in to a particular label quickly.

Comment: Do you need the notification to specifically identify the label of the email that you receive or do you just have some labels that are a higher priority and only want to know when any email bearing any of those important labels comes in?  If you are looking for the latter, I have a suggestion, if you need the former, I do not.

Comment: @matthew read - I did mean labels.  @matt - I want to have a small number of labels use a different ringtone (or none in one case).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just happened upon the **[GMail Label Notifier](https://market.android.com/details?id=org.hubris.gmailnotifierpro)** app.  I think this will do exactly what you want.

Comment: It looks like it's working pretty well.  Accepting this answer instead of the other.   In addition to customized sound and LED color, it creates a notification that takes you straight to that label in your inbox.

Answer (score 5):

This has recently become a feature in the native GMail app.

Comment: Thanks Paul.    I've retired GMail Label Notifier since this update (Version 2.3.5).

Answer (score 0):

**No**, not in the native Gmail App.

Comment: Hopefully they'll add this at some point.

Comment: Take a look at the other answer I left, I think that'll work.

Answer (score 0):

Yes they can!

```
Open GMail App
Settings
Select Account
Manage Labels
Select Label
Select "Sync Messages"
Customize!
```

[image]

[image]