# Notification of new label e-mails

Tags: gmail, notifications

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can gmail notifications be customized by label?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/6567/can-gmail-notifications-be-customized-by-label)

I have a filter in gmail that sets some of the mail to skip the inbox and be archived (unread) under a specific label. On the desktop Gmail, this label is shown alongside my regular inbox, which makes everything nice and organized.

Unfortunately, on my Gmail android app, I don't get notified of any of these e-mails that skip the inbox and go to this label. I have already set this label to be synced by the app, but I'm still not getting notifications. How can I get notified of e-mails that skip the inbox and go straight to a specific label?

So far I've only found [Gmail Label Notifier](https://market.android.com/details?id=org.hubris.gmailnotifierpro), but I don't need all this customization and I was hoping to find something free.

Comment: Workaround: Create a second GMail account, and have those messages additionally forwarded to it.  Then you'll get notifications for both accounts if you add it on Android, effectively giving you notifications for that label.

Comment: I asked a similar question in http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/6567/can-gmail-notifications-be-customized-by-label and ended up installing the Gmail Label Notifier; it's worked well for me.

Comment: @Matthew That's a good idea, I might go with that.

Comment: @TomG I saw that question, I believed it wasn't a duplicated because I specifically said I didn't need any customization, and I was looking for something free. But that's alright.

Answer (score 1):

Don't know quite how you've got it configured to show your non-inbox mail alongside your main mail in the web interface, but if you're using the Priority Inbox features of GMail then you can set up separate alert settings on Android for mails detected as priority messages, see this Google Mobile blog entry: [Gmail for Android: better Priority Inbox support and improved compose](http://googlemobile.blogspot.com/2010/12/gmail-for-android-better-priority-inbox.html)

> Ever wanted to know that you got an
>   important message without taking your
>   phone out of your pocket? Now you can
>   set up your phone to notify, vibrate,
>   or ring on just your new important
>   mail (check out Menu > Settings >
>   Priority Inbox).

Comment: Unfortunately, my gmail app doesn't support Priority inbox, as I'm running 2.1. But it looks like it would have worked otherwise.